# How to set the border of any Object(Rect preferably) without changing its original dimensions

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have been exploring FabricJS for some time and in one specific context where I have a number of adjoining rectangles on a canvas I want to create a border for each rectangle to differentiate them from one another. I tried out using stroke but this changes the original dimensions of the rectangle. Suppose a want a rectangle of width 50 , height 50 using stroke increases the dimensions of my rectangle. I tried out the borderColor property of objects as well but this seems to be applied only on the bounding box(selection control box). How do I add a border to an object in FabricJS without changing its dimensions and without creating any new entity such as another new line/rectangle to wrap the original rectangle.